# fscanf Giving weird characters in front

Tags: c++

Whenever I `fscanf()` from a file, I'm getting weird characters scanned from `fscanf()`.

This is the first line of the file I'm trying to scan:

```
Derek Stevens,9/28/1959
```

And this is the output that I'm getting after `cout`'ing everything:

```
Birthdate search program
Name: ∩╗┐Derek Stevens: 16 characters.
Born: 9281959
```

Notice the characters in front of `Derek`.

This is the function I'm using, the `month` attribute is not being used yet, that will be used later for sorting.

```
bool readBirthDate(int month) {

        Employee tempEmployee;
        int nameLength = 0;
        char tempName[256]{};

        fscanf(fptr, "%[^,],%d/%d/%d\n", tempName, &tempEmployee.m_month, &tempEmployee.m_day, &tempEmployee.m_year);

        nameLength = strlen(tempName);  

        cout << "Name: " << tempName << ": " << nameLength << " characters." << endl;
        cout << "Born: " << tempEmployee.m_month << tempEmployee.m_day << tempEmployee.m_year << endl;

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Path of least resistance: Open file in a text editor and resave it as an ASCII file.

Answer (score 5):

Three characters is a suspicious number, as it happens to be the exact same length as the optional prefix UTF-8 files can have to announce that this is the encoding being used. This is also know as the Byte Order Mark (see on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark))

The BOM for UTF-8 is the following three bytes: `EF` `BB` `BF`. If those happened to be the codes for these three characters in your terminal's encoding, then we could be pretty confident that the file you are reading has such a prefix to it.

And it turns out, in the [IBM437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) encoding, commonly used by DOS, `EF` `BB` `BF` is exactly `∩╗┐`.

The correct way to fix this, assuming that your program is only meant to consume ASCII/UTF-8 files, is to check if the file starts with this sequence, and skip the first three bytes if that's the case.

If you absolutely must stick with the stdio interface, it could look like this:

```
bool try_utf_8_bom(FILE* fptr) {
    auto pos = ftell(fptr);

    unsigned char data[3];
    auto count = fread(data, 1, 3, fptr);

    if(count != 3 || data[0] != 0xEF || data[1] != 0xBB || data[2] != 0xBF) {
       // Not the UTF-8 BOM, undo the read.
       fseek(fptr, pos, SEEK_SET);
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```